# Unable to set foreign keys in the table structure in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, key

I cannot set foreign keys in my table structure in laravel. I've pretty much tried all solutions mentionned here and none of them are working.

First of all, I made a table named 'categories'

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
}
```

Then, I made another class named 'exercices'  **with no foreign keys yet**

```
class CreateExercicesTable extends Migration{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('exercices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('categorie_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('imageUrl');
        $table->timestamps();
        //$table->foreign('categorie_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('exercices');
}
```

}

After that, I run the command *php artisan migrate:fresh* to start from scratch the tables. Everything runs perfectly fine.

```
Migrating: 2020_02_11_004702_create_categories_table
Migrated:  2020_02_11_004702_create_categories_table (0.06 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_02_11_005524_create_exercices_table
Migrated:  2020_02_11_005524_create_exercices_table (0.05 seconds)
```

But now, if I remove the double slashes before the "//$table->foreign('categorie_id')->references('id')->on('categories');" then run "php artisan migrate" I get the following message: "Nothing to migrate."

After that, I tried to do "php artisan migrate:fresh" to make sure the foreign key is added correctly but I get this error message

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table `exercices` () default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at /home/vagrant/code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try using ->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')

Comment: what Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Bit of a long shot but, you haven't changed your character set for the database at all? Have you also tried to empty the database and run your tables in fresh?

Comment: You can't just re-run a migration. You have to rollback first. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations

Comment: Just noticed you have tried a refresh as well, which would get around that problem. Looks like in your `config/database.php` file you have `'collation' => "'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"` or similar. Note the extra quotes in the error message.